# Ubuntu in a virtualbox 6.1 VM suddenly experiencing UI/graphical rendering problems

Tags: graphics, virtualbox

I've been running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS in a VM for a few months and everything has been great. The UI was quick and snappy with no real delays or stuttering. I did some routine updates in the past 3 weeks and suddenly the performance is awful. Going to the app drawer takes a few seconds and it only paints a few frames. It looks like a slideshow. When I come back to the VM from a long period of host computer inactivity (but on-- not suspended or hibernated), the UI is completely destroyed and cannot render itself properly any longer. I need to reboot the VM to regain usability for another few hours.
Any idea what may be wrong? Anything I can force revert or update to get past the current experience?

edit: I find that when I change resolutions on the host machine it's more likely to cause this problem. I am normally at 3840x2160, but will sometime switch to 1920x1200 to access the host over VNC.

[image]
[image]
[image]